# Excel - Unable to open https// <<PATH>> Cannot download the information you requested ---- How to disable

Tags: excel

How can I disable "Unable to open https// ...PATH... Cannot download the information you requested" messages? I am getting this when I open some files. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 3):

I edit my message with the following link where you will find the solution: 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2011/11/15/quot-cannot-download-the-information-you-requested-quot-executing-web-query-from-excel.aspx

It is related to webqueries though.

Comment: +1 doesn't really disable the message like they asked, but might give a lead in solving the issue

Comment: This may work for PC users - what about poor Mac Office 2011 users? We can't very well alter IE settings...

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, here are the steps to resolve it.
You need to edit the registry and add a key
Click on Start -->  Run, type `regedit` then press enter.
Locate the registry key below, it could be any of these depending on the OS and Office version

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet\ 
OR
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet\
OR
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Internet\ 
OR
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Internet
```

The version number could be 9.0, 15.0, 12.0 etc. but **always use the one which already has the common\internet subkeys**

After you have located it, do the following

1. Make sure the **Internet** subkey is selected. On the **Edit** menu,
   point to **New**, and then click DWORD Value. Add the following
   registry value:
   **Value Name**: ForceShellExecute
2. Double-click **ForceShellExecute**, and then set the **Value data to 1.** Click **OK**.
3. On the **Registry** menu, click **Exit**.

The solution is taken and modified from [MS kb218153](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/218153)
**PS:** The original support kb article is incomplete, since it mentions only 9.0, I solved this on a Windows 7 64 Bit and Office 2013 Pro and the registry key I added was in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Internet

Comment: Good tip, but still doesn't solve the issue on my Winblows computer.

Comment: I have office 2013, and I put it in 15, and it didn't work. Then I added to 9 and it works. Thanks