# EXcel - unable to open URL: Cannot download the information you requested

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I write some URL in EXCEL file using Apache POI. This is my code:

```
Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(org.apache.poi.common.usermodel.Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
link.setAddress(cellVallue);
cell1.setHyperlink(link);
```

When I dowload the file, I am not able to open the URL on browser and I get this message

> unable to open "url". Cannot download the information you requested

But, I noticed weired behavior : 
 when I copy and paste the url from Excel to the IE browser and I execute it. 
After that, I can open the url from Excel directly on IE borwser without get the message and it works fine!

Comment: Example of link: "http ://localhost/mf-web/list?numero=1258". I didn't understand what is the file robots.txt ?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. Does this problem happen even with an external URL? Try to point to an external URL you know that works if you didn't try this yet. This test is only to know if the problem is the URL you are trying to access.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem completely. Can you explain again the steps that you followed and when the error happens exactly?

Comment: @Fagner Fonseca: thx for your reply, the problem happen when I click to the URL text in the Excel file. The URL is web page in my application web.

Comment: Did you try to point to an external URL? For example: http://www.google.com. I noticed that you are using a link for download, try to access this link: https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz. Check if both URLs will work in your code.

Comment: Which POI version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 3.12 of Apache POI, the URL is pointed to an application Web hosted in a particular server. I noticed that if the URL is currently in the server cache then the EXcel open it directly in the IE browser.

Answer (score 1):

There could be couple of reasons for that as actually it is not just a regular link, I assume your link is returning some stream to download and also assuming that your hyperlink is actually working when you copy and paste it to (any) browser.

There are some known issues as you may end up adding some keys to your registry.

**Short suggestion is:**
Try setting internet explorer as your default browser and see if it will work. That would at least give you some idea about the actual issues and you could make sure that issue is not the way you generate the link in the excel. It is something behind the scene.

If still not works , Open IE and click on Tools / Internet Options / Advanced then scroll down to the Security settings and untick the box for ‘Do not save encrypted pages to disk’ as shown below:that Internet Explorer Settings are like below:

[image]

Obviously this is not a "solution" as it is not a good idea to force your users to use a specific browser. (Personally I hate it when they do!)

There are couple other options but they all clearly mentioned in [this awesome post](https://techlogon.com/how-to-fix-a-cannot-download-the-information-you-requested-error-message-on-hyperlinks/) as it is the original source of my answer anyways.

Also I would suggest to look [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2011/11/15/cannot-download-the-information-you-requested-executing-web-query-from-excel/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579714/excel-unable-to-open-https-path-cannot-download-the-information-you-requ) posts as well.